# Need to set dynamic value for ngModel sent from input in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

There are two address shipping and billing Country. Both has different value.
Components are reused here. 
A select-country component was made for this .

```
<select-country [addressType]="'shipping'"></select-country>
<select-country [addressType]="'billing'"></select-country>
```

The type can be shipping or billing.

Now in select-country

```js
 
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild, ElementRef,Input  } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfigService } from '../services/config.service';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';
import { CheckOutService } from '../services/checkout/check-out.service';
import { HomeService } from './../services/banner/home.service';
import {MdlService} from './../services/material-design-lite/mdl.service';
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import { apiUrl,used_currency,used_language } from './../services/global.constant';
 import { Router,ActivatedRoute  } from '@angular/router';
import {NgSelectModule, NgOption} from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

declare var componentHandler: any;
@Component({
 moduleId: module.id + '',
  selector: 'select-country',
  templateUrl: './get-country.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./get-country.component.css'] 
})
export class GetCountryComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input('addressType') addressType; 
 searchQuery: string = '';
  items;va;
  countries = new Array; 
  constructor(public http: Http,public router: Router,
   public configz: ConfigService,public shared: DataService,
    private checkOutservice: CheckOutService ,
    private service: HomeService, public material:MdlService) { 
     if(this.addressType=='shipping')
     {va=shared.orderDetails.delivery_country}
    else{va=shared.orderDetails.billing_country}
    var data = { type: 'null' };
    http.post(this.configz.url + 'getCountries', data).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
      
      this.items = this.countries = data.data;
      console.log(this.items);
      setTimeout(() => {  this.material.render(); }, 550);
    });
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){

  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  static mdlWrapper(element: ElementRef) {

        componentHandler.upgradeElement(element.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

```html
                                        <div   tabindex="-1">
                                            <select  [(ngModel)]="shared.orderDetails.delivery_country" name="orderby"  > 
                                             <option *ngFor="let item of items" value=""  >{{ item.countries_name }}</option>
                                                 
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
```

Shared is service which is shared among all component. 
For shipping shared.orderDetails.delivery_country is used and for billing shared.orderDetails.billing_country

How to dynamically change ngModel and set shared.orderDetails .
I am making changes in shared only because there are multiple component  and they need to share the same service to retain data.

EDIT : I tried setting a variable in Get Country Component. Edited it please check. It does not update the shared.orederDetails.

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, please provide it in your question. What is the expected behavior and what is the current behavior?

Comment: They point here is the data will only be avaible after you finish the call and set the data (async). So if you go to quick the data is not ready yet. This can be tricky. And how you want to implement it, can do with setters and getters, but I have no clue how your functionalities should work.

Comment: @vincecampanale   i have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you build the `<select-country>` as a proper form control? That way you can use `ngModel` binding and forget about the details. Something like this:

```
<form>
  <input [(ngModel)]="order.name" name="name">
  <input [(ngModel)]="order.count" name="count"> 
  <select-country [(ngModel)]="order.shippingCountry" name="shippingCountry"></select-country>
  <select-country [(ngModel)]="order.billingCountry" name="billingCountry"></select-country>
</form>
```

The component you can build like this:

```
import { Component, Input, forwardRef, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

interface Country {
  value: string;
  countryName: string;
}

const SELECT_COUNTRY_VALUE_ACCESSOR = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => SelectCountryComponent),
    multi: true,
};
@Component({
  selector: 'select-country',
  template: `
<div tabindex="-1">
  <select  [(ngModel)]="value" name="orderby" (ngModelChange)="updateValue($event)"> 
    <option *ngFor="let country of countries"  [selected]="country.value === value?.value" [value]="country.value">{{ country.countryName }}</option>
  </select>
</div>`,
  styles: [`:host { display: inline-block; }`],
  providers: [SELECT_COUNTRY_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class SelectCountryComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {
  _value: Country;

  countries = []
  private onChangeCallback: Function;
  private onTouchedCallback: Function;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('https://www.mocky.io/v2/5a90341e2f000061006caba7')
      .subscribe((countries: Country[]) => this.countries = countries,
      err => console.error('Error getting countries:', err));
  }
  /** that mock should return something like this:
   *     [{
           "countryName": "Ireland",
           "value": "IRELAND" // or whatever
    }, ...]
   */

  // update coming from external, e.g. form control
  writeValue(value) {
    // outside change of selected item
    console.log('Update value:', value);
    this._value = value;
  }

  // update coming from the view (our dropdown), we update it and then go on to inform Angular Forms.
  // called by the dropdown selector.
  updateValue(value) {
    this._value = this.countries.filter(country => country.value === value)[0];
    this.valueChange();
  }

  private valueChange() {
    this.onTouchedCallback();
    this.onChangeCallback(this._value);
  }

  // these two are set
  registerOnChange(onChangeCallback: Function) {
    this.onChangeCallback = onChangeCallback;
  }
  registerOnTouched(onTouchedCallback: any) {
    this.onTouchedCallback = onTouchedCallback;
  }
}
```

Of course, adjust to oyur needs, add validation, styling etc. You can see it in action here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-country-picker?file=app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my other answer (with proposal to make a lil' standalone component you could reuse elsewhere), let's try a more direct approach, fixing your code:

First, your template `options` all lack values. Even when your user picks something, ngModel doesn't change (because it's always the same value, "").

```
<div tabindex="-1">
    <select  [(ngModel)]="shared.orderDetails.delivery_country" name="orderby"> 
      <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.countries_name">{{ item.countries_name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Second, your init logic is in the constructor. At that instance, you still don't have your inputs settled. Move init parts to your ngOnInit.
    constructor(public http: Http,
                public router: Router,
                public configz: ConfigService,
                public shared: DataService,
                private checkOutservice: CheckOutService,
                private service: HomeService,
                public material:MdlService) { 
    }

```
ngOnInit() {
  if(this.addressType === 'shipping') {
    this.va = shared.orderDetails.delivery_country
  } else {
    this.va = shared.orderDetails.billing_country;
  }
  const  data = { type: 'null' };
  http.post(this.configz.url + 'getCountries', data).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {      
        this.items = this.countries = data.data;
        console.log(this.items);
        setTimeout(() => {  this.material.render(); }, 550);
  });
}
```